# Logic behind Fast input

Tags: c++, input

Can somebody explain the logic behind this fast input?I know its faster than scanf.

```
int scan()
{
    int ip=getchar_unlocked(),ret=0;
        for(;ip<'0'||ip>'9';ip=getchar_unlocked());

        for(;ip>='0'&&ip<='9';ip=getchar_unlocked())
            ret=ret*10+ip-'0';
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Got it Vaughn Cato!!Thanx..

Answer (score 3):

The `unlocked` part here is to avoid locking the input file (thus potentially causing problems if multiple threads are reading from the same input).

This is probably where 90% of the gains are, compared to other using `getchar`, and that in turn is probably only marginally better than `scanf`. Obviously, `scanf` also has overhead in parsing the format string, which may be a bit of an overhead.

The rest of the code is simply "skip anything that isn't a digit", then read a decimal number into `ret`, stopping when the digit is a non-digit.

For reading vast number of inputs, I would suggest using `fread` (or `mmap` or `MapViewoOfFile` if the system is known to support one of those calls) to load up a large amount of input data in a buffer, and then use a pointer-based method to "skip over non-digits" (assuming this is a "safe" thing to do). Highly likely that this is faster again than the code above.